# how to make an android app to display only a specific group of companies

Tags: android, android-mapview

The app is just to display, say, only the Walmart stores on mapview in my app and when I click on each store, I get more information about the store, more like a "Walmart store locator" I have knowledge of how to create android apps and little knowledge on Google Maps V2 .
P.S: Walmart is just an example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is not very specific, I am giving a general idea. You could have a custom class storing all the relevant details about a store.

```
public class StoreListItem {
    private String store_id = null;
    private String city = null;
    private String store_type = null;
    private String name = null;
    private String store_address = null;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private Bitmap defaultMarker = null;

    public StoreListItem(...) {
        // Constructor
        // Initialize the elements with incoming values
    }

    // Any other getter/setter methods 
}
```

And then you can use this ArrayList itself, or create new marker list which will be linked to this StoreListItem through store_id or whatever identifier you might be having.

Comment: You probably didn't read the question well, I just want my Points of interest which would be my Walmart stores displayed in the google map of ny android app, and it should be clickable